# Reduce sample rate of GPS data based on distance between points

Tags: scala, geospatial, signal-processing, apache-spark

The algorithm needs to reduce an `RDD[GPSRecord]` based on the distance between several points, e.g. "give me only GPS records when the distance between them exceeds 15m".

Right now the algorithm is not interpolating points. It collects a point if it detects that the next value has a distance between it and the last point collected greater than the distance `samplePeriod` provided.

I'm new to both Scala and Spark so I would like to know if there's a better way to achieve this.

```
def filterByDistance(gpsRecords:RDD[GPSRecord], distanceSamplePeriod:Int ):RDD[GPSRecord] = {
    val firstGPSRecord = gpsRecords.first()
    val firstRecord: (Double, GPSRecord) = (0, firstGPSRecord)

    // Calculate distance between each point and the next one
    val slidedRecords = RDDFunctions.fromRDD(gpsRecords)
        .sliding(2)
        .map(gpsRecords => {
            (
                utils.getDistanceBetweenPoints(
                    (gpsRecords(0).latitude, gpsRecords(0).longitude),
                    (gpsRecords(1).latitude, gpsRecords(1).longitude)
                ),
                gpsRecords
            )
        })

    // Per partition, for each record calculate the distance traveled relative to the partition starting point
    val partitionRelativeRecords = slidedRecords.mapPartitions(recordsWithDistanceIterator => {
        var distance: Double = 0

        recordsWithDistanceIterator.map(recordsWithDistanceTuple => {
            val accumulatedDistance = recordsWithDistanceTuple._1 + distance
            distance = recordsWithDistanceTuple._1 + distance

            (
                accumulatedDistance,
                recordsWithDistanceTuple._2(1)
            )
        })
    })

    // Get total distance of each partition
    val lastValues = partitionRelativeRecords.mapPartitions(recordIterator => {
        var records: (Double, GPSRecord) = null
        while ( recordIterator.hasNext ) {
            records = recordIterator.next
        }

        Iterator.single(records._1)
    }).collect()

    // Per partition, for each record sum the distance traveled on previous partitions
    var recordsWithDistance = partitionRelativeRecords.mapPartitionsWithIndex((partition, partitionRelativeRecords) => {
        var accumulatedDistance: Double = 0
        for ( i <- 0 until partition ) {
            accumulatedDistance += lastValues(i)
        }

        partitionRelativeRecords.map(partitionRelativeRecord => {
            (
                partitionRelativeRecord._1 + accumulatedDistance,
                partitionRelativeRecord._2
            )
        })
    }, preservesPartitioning = true)

    // Due to the sliding the first record was lost, add it again
    recordsWithDistance = context.parallelize(Array(firstRecord), 1).union(recordsWithDistance)

    // Slide the records again to have the distance of the current record and the next one
    val slidedRecordArrays = RDDFunctions.fromRDD(recordsWithDistance).sliding(2)

    // Compare both distances to see if divided by the requested distanceSamplePeriod the next point exceeds the threshold
    // and collect the next point (no interpolation for now...)
    recordsWithDistance = slidedRecordArrays.map(recordArrays => {
        if ( Math.floor(recordArrays(1)._1 / distanceSamplePeriod) > Math.floor(recordArrays(0)._1 / distanceSamplePeriod) ) recordArrays(1)
        else null
    }).filter(_ != null)

    // The second sliding removed the first element again, add it
    recordsWithDistance = context.parallelize(Array(firstRecord), 1).union(recordsWithDistance)

    // Return only the GPSRecord
    recordsWithDistance.map(_._2)
}
```